# Angular cli load external ng modules

Tags: angular

Is it possible to load external angular2 app's modules in angular cli.

Angular2 App "A" is distributed on a server  in my case its `test|01.azurewebsites.net`.

and I have another Angular2 app "B" distributed on a server  `test|02.azurewebsites.net`.

- Can I get the "A"'s appModule in "B" at run time? Is it possible ?

I would really appreciate any ideas about this specific problem.

Kind Regards!